# On Bootstrap Accordion, is there a way to add a fixed save button to title when collapsed?

Tags: javascript, css, html, twitter-bootstrap

Is it possible, On a Bootstrap Accordion, to add a fixed save button to the title of the accordion when it is collapsed? so that when the user expands an accordion, they can enter information and always save it from the fixed button on the title bar? See below.

basically (since I can't post an image)

Here is what I mean

*> title of accordion (collapsed)     [save button]

*> title of accordion (expanded)      [save button]

input boxes

input boxes

*> title of accordion (collapsed)     [save button]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add this HTML inside each `.accordion-heading`:

```
<button class="btn btn-save">Save</button>
```

Then add this CSS:

```
.btn-save{
    position:absolute;
    right:2px;
    top:2px;
}
.accordion-heading{
    position:relative;
}
```

This will add a button inside each the header of each accordion, but clicking the button won't expand or collapse the accordion. You can give each button a different id and then use that to attach event handlers.

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jdwire/gz3s4/3/